# SUM of a field in INNER JOIN in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT      pt.id, 
            pt.plan_name,
            pt.product_disc_amt,
            pt.product_disc_perc, 
            SUM(ac.premium_amount) AS premium,
            ac.id AS ac_id 
FROM        product pt 
INNER JOIN  age_classification ac 
ON          ac.p_id = pt.id 
WHERE       pt.medical_coverage_for = 'dependents_only'
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 3 AND ac.age_to::  int >= 3  
AND         ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single') 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 4 AND ac.age_to::  int >= 4  
AND         ac.gender = 'male' AND ac.marital_status = 'single' ) 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 2 
AND         ac.age_to::  int >= 2  AND ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single')    
GROUP BY    pt.id, 
            ac.premium_amount,
            ac.id
```

In this query, age_classification is a One2Many relation to product. It's related through `p_id`.

I am getting o/p like this:

```
id      plan_name   product_disc_amt    product_disc_perc       premium         ac_id
295     A           0                   0                       110             75
1543    B           0                   0                       90              69
1543    B           0                   0                       95              70
1543    B           0                   0                       132             71
```

My expected output is:

```
id      plan_name   product_disc_amt    product_disc_perc       premium         ac_id
295     A           0                   0                       110             75
1543    B           0                   0                       317             69 <------ Sample Value
```

ac_id need not be 69. I just wrote there an id which was in the output that I am getting. It's not necessary to have a value in `ac_id`. I just gave the column to show the relation.  Since it is given in the `SELECT` statement, I don't know what value will come in the expected output. So I have given a value.

That is I want to get the sum of the `premium_amount` on id `1543`. The row is being repeated. Since I am new to SQL, I am not getting a workaround of this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would the `ac_id` be 69 for the output row?  How would you pick between the three rows that are returned without the correct grouping?

Comment: @Martin ,Sorry ac_id need not be 69. I just wrote there an id which was in the o/p that I am getting. It's not necessary to have a value in ac_id. I just gave the column to show the relation.  Since it is given in the `SELECT` statement, I don't know what value will come in the expected o/p. So I have given a value.

Comment: By your own admission "It's not necessary to have a value in ac_id".  Then don't have it there - remove it from the select and group list and . It being there is the reason you get the results you getting instead of what you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also take `plan_name` into `GROUP BY`. The column `ac_id` also prevents the rows from being combined. Here an aggregate could help:

```
SELECT      pt.id, 
            pt.plan_name,
            pt.product_disc_amt,
            pt.product_disc_perc, 
            SUM(ac.premium_amount) AS premium,
            MAX(ac.id) AS ac_id
FROM        product pt 
INNER JOIN  age_classification ac 
ON          ac.p_id = pt.id 
WHERE       pt.medical_coverage_for = 'dependents_only'
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 3 AND ac.age_to::  int >= 3  
AND         ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single') 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 4 AND ac.age_to::  int >= 4  
AND         ac.gender = 'male' AND ac.marital_status = 'single' ) 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 2 
AND         ac.age_to::  int >= 2  AND ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single')    
GROUP BY    pt.id, 
            pt.plan_name,
            ac.premium_amount,
            pt.product_disc_perc
```

Comment: It looks like "ac_id" is not necessary. This is correct, but bear in mind that this field result means nothing in terms of interpretation.

Comment: I have added `MAX(ac.id) AS ac_id` in SELECT and `pt.plan_name` in GROUP, but still it is showing 3 rows.

Comment: Ah, I missed pt.product_disc_perc in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your current results, I understand that you want records group by `id` and `plan_name`.

`ac_id` should go in an aggregate function, probably `min()`.

Also, you want to remove column  `ac.premium` from the `group by` clause, since you are using an aggregate function on it.

Finally: I would assume that columns `product_disc_amt` and `product_disc_perc` are functionlay dependent on the other columns that are part of the `group by` clause (otherwise, you would need to add them to the `group by` clause as well).

Consider:

```
SELECT      pt.id, 
            pt.plan_name,
            pt.product_disc_amt,
            pt.product_disc_perc, 
            SUM(ac.premium_amount) AS premium,
            MIN(ac.id) AS ac_id 
FROM        product pt 
INNER JOIN  age_classification ac 
ON          ac.p_id = pt.id 
WHERE       pt.medical_coverage_for = 'dependents_only'
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 3 AND ac.age_to::int >= 3  
AND         ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single') 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 4 AND ac.age_to::int >= 4  
AND         ac.gender = 'male' AND ac.marital_status = 'single' ) 
OR          (ac.relationship = 'child' AND ac.age_from::int <= 2 
AND         ac.age_to::int >= 2  AND ac.gender = 'female' AND ac.marital_status = 'single')    
GROUP BY    pt.id, 
            pt.plan_name
```